# Is it possible that when using sudo command it should first source a file?

Tags: linux, bash, ansible, sudo

I need to run a bunch of scripts (with sudo) that use a single file.sh as a configuration file for all. Initially I've put the file.sh in /etc/profile.d and when I ran the scripts as root everything was ok (because when I connected to the machine it first sourced the file.sh and all vars in that file were available) but now, for security reasons, I need to run them with another user with sudo rights.

When running with sudo the "configuration file" in /etc/profile.d does not get sourced even if I'm root and do sudo - it's the same.

Using "sudo -E" is not an option, also this kind of solution "Defaults env_keep += "ftp_proxy http_proxy https_proxy no_proxy"" does not work for me as the vars in the file change a lot and it's easier to throw a file, with all the vars, in a location - like /etc/profile.d/ - instead to adding options to  /etc/sudoers.

**Later Edit (working):**

Moved original sudo command to sudo.orig. Created a new sudo bash script

```
[root@NS1 bin]# cat sudo
#!/bin/bash
source /etc/profile.d/set_env_vmdeploy.sh
sh /usr/bin/sudo.orig "$@"
```

and gave it permissions

```
[root@NS1 bin]# chmod 4111 sudo
[root@NS1 bin]# ll sudo*
---s--x--x 1 root root     78 May  7 13:42 sudo
---s--x--x 1 root root 123832 Jul 31  2014 sudo.orig
```

Comment: Do you mean `than to modify other files` ?

Comment: I don't understand you question. I need some variables stored in a file.sh to be sourced/available when I run "sudo some_script.sh".

Comment: So you mean `then`? Sorry, it's just people use them interchangably and it completely changed the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: I guess you could put a wrapper around `sudo`... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200924/run-a-script-only-at-shutdown-not-log-off-or-restart-on-mac-os-x/24202568#24202568

Comment: It's really hard to read code and output in comments. Please click `edit` underneath your original question and update it with any new, relevant information.

Comment: You didn't pass the arguments through from the wrapper to the original... `exec /usr/bin/sudo.orig "$@"`

Comment: Also, I am not sure that `exec` is actually the correct way to invoke `sudo.orig` in your case, since that *replaces* the current process into which you have sourced the environment. I know I used `exec` in the script I linked to, but that was different. Maybe you just need to run `sudo.orig` here, rather than `exec` it.

Answer (score 4):

If you want `sudo` to execute all the profile scripts in the child shell, you can tell it to invoke the shell as a login shell: `sudo -i /usr/local/bin/my_script.sh`. (Note that the child shell will start with the working directory set to `/root`, and also that this may have other unintended side effects.)

Alternatively, invoke bash explicitly with a command parameter: `sudo /bin/bash -c "source ./config.sh; ./real_script.sh"`.

Comment: What I needed was what @Mark Setchell suggested

Comment: I would say that the method I suggest is significantly cleaner than renaming the sudo executable - among other things, it won't break next time you do an apt/yum update that overwrites your sudo binary.

Comment: I agree with you but for what I need it (tens of shell commands) it's easier than modifing all the commands by adding stuff at the end. I'm running sudo with ansible - so implementing your solution for this specific case would be an ton of work for me with adding -c "source /file.sh" for each shell command. Thanks