# Changing default voice via terrminal Mac OS x

Tags: macos, text-to-speech, voice

I would like to change the default voice via terminal. Is there a better (and less repetitive way) to change the default voice than `say -v 'Alex' 'Hello world'`. ***I really do not want*** to go into my program and change all my `os.system("say 'Foo'")` as I have many. I am using Mac OS x High Sierra Version 10.13.3. I am making the program that I mention in python. If you need any more info, comment. Thank you in advance,

*user 9311010*

Comment: You could put a wrapper around the `say` command that uses your chosen voice, like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24202568/2836621

Comment: Or you could run `os.system("echo $PATH")` (just once to test) and see if there is any directory ahead of `/usr/bin` (where the real `say` lives) in the PATH and add a new script to that directory because it will get executed in preference to the standard one if it is to the left on the PATH.

Comment: Or you could do `export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/overrides` in your login profile, and create a script called `$HOME/overrides/say` which just does `/usr/bin/say -v Tessa "$@"`